# When I using kubernetes api to health check grpc server, need proto? or not?

Tags: kubernetes, protocol-buffers, grpc, health-check

```
from kubernetes import client, config
from grpc_health.v1 import health_pb2, health_pb2_grpc
import grpc.experimental.aio as aio
import asyncio

async def check_grpc_health(ip, port):
    try:
        channel = aio.insecure_channel(f"{ip}:{port}")
        stub = health_pb2_grpc.HealthStub(channel)
        response = await stub.Check(health_pb2.HealthCheckRequest(service=""), timeout=1)  
        await channel.close()
        return response.status == health_pb2.HealthCheckResponse.SERVING
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error checking health of gRPC service at {ip}:{port}: {e}")
        return False

async def check_pod_health(pod):
    ip = pod.status.pod_ip
    port = None
    if pod.spec.containers and pod.spec.containers[0].ports:
        port = pod.spec.containers[0].ports[0].container_port
    if ip is not None and await check_grpc_health(ip, port):
        print(f"Pod {pod.metadata.name} is healthy.")
    else:
        print(f"Pod {pod.metadata.name} is unhealthy, consider restarting.")

async def main():
    config.load_kube_config()
    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    namespace = "apple-engine"
    label_selector = "grpc-health-check"

    print("finding...")
    pods = await v1.list_namespaced_pod(namespace=namespace, watch=False)
    print(len(pods.items))

    tasks = [check_pod_health(pod) for pod in pods.items]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I'm writing this health check python code with kubernetes api, but not consider the proto file.

If I use this health check code, need proto file or not?
Just want to check the connection with proto, not exactly consider about namespace and label selector

Answer (score 0):

The [gRPC](https://grpc.io) project provides a [PyPI](https://pypi.org) implementation of the [gRPC Health Checking protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md) called [`grpcio-health-checking`](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-health-checking) that you can use.